# How to delete all the empty rows in a datagirdview?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to delete the empty rows from a column. Here is what I've tried but does not work, I am getting an error as "use 'new' keyword to create an object instance"! Your help would be appreciated, thanks so much.

```
For i= data.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
Dim row As DataGridViewRow = data.Rows(i)
If (Not row.IsNewRow Andalso data.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.Tostring() = "") Then
data.Rows.RemoveAt(i)

Else
End If
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?  Are you missing the word "row" in front of IsNewRow?

Comment: Thanks for the response. that was the typo, I am not missing the word "row" and getting that error when it reaches to the "If" line! Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce that error on my machine.  Don't assume Cells(X).Value isn't null.  Check first.

Comment: what error is it displaying? also add a verification for null with Cells(1).Value.IsDBNull

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments. how can I check the cell values are or are not null?

Comment: It was already answered, by checking if its null or empty with IsDBNull orelse "" <emprty string

Comment: Thanks! I used different approach and worked! :)         For i= data.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.cell(1).Value) Then
data.Rows.RemoveAt(i)

End If

Answer (score 0):

i would try to filter the data prior to insertion in the datagridview. For example:

```
myReader = MyDCommand.ExecuteReader
While myReader.Read
If Not myReader("Mfr_Id") Is DBNull.Value Then
    If myReader("MfrGroup") = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text Then
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add(New Object() {myReader("Mfr_Id"), _
        myReader("MfrName"), myReader("WebPath"), _
        myReader("MfrGroup"), ""})
    End If
End If
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it work using this code...

Thanks all!

```
For i= data.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.cell(1).Value) Then
data.Rows.RemoveAt(i)

End If
```